# I want to add terms from a Choice column to the Refiners list in a Content Search Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I want to add terms from a Choice column to the Refiners list in a Content Search Web Part.  I figured this out once but I can't figure it out again.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Map the crawled property to a refinablestringxx managed property in search schema and crawl again. Add refinablestring in the refinement webpart. Should work.

Comment: I found the Crawled Properties in Search Schema.  How do I link the Crawled Property to the Library / Choice column (named Document Type)?

Comment: You map the crawled property to a RefinableString managed property. Add some items in the list and wait for the crawl. The refinablestring property will be populated automatically after crawl

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below to add column value to refiners list:

1. Make sure the choice column has been given value in the list/library.
2. In Managed Property, select and edit a managed property which hasn’t map a crawled property such as RefinableString00.
3. Add a Mapping with choice column crawled property.
4. Wait for some time to crawl the new managed property.
5. If there is no value for refiners list, go to site settings->search and offline availability->click “Reindex site”, then wait some time to crawl.